# "info functions" gives a lot of unwanted functions name which is not in my binary in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Here is my c code

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    int add(int a,int b){
        int sum=0;
        sum = a+b;
        return sum;
    }
    
    int sub(int a ,int b){
        int sub=0;
        sub = a-b;
        return sub;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        int a = atoi(argv[1]);
        int b = atoi(argv[2]);
        printf("Sum of %d and %d = %d",a,b,add(a,b));
        printf("Sub of %d and %d = %d",a,b,sub(a,b));
    }
```

I compiled it by giving this command

```
    gcc -ggdb calculator.c -o calculator
```

Then I opened in in gdb. After setting breakpoint at "main" and tried to list all the functions by the command "info functions"..But it gives a bunch of huge other functions name.Here is some of them;
All defined functions:

```
File ../argp/argp-fmtstream.h:
266:    size_t __argp_fmtstream_point(argp_fmtstream_t);
220:    int __argp_fmtstream_putc(argp_fmtstream_t, int);
207:    int __argp_fmtstream_puts(argp_fmtstream_t, const char *);
230:    size_t __argp_fmtstream_set_lmargin(argp_fmtstream_t, size_t);
242:    size_t __argp_fmtstream_set_rmargin(argp_fmtstream_t, size_t);
254:    size_t __argp_fmtstream_set_wmargin(argp_fmtstream_t, size_t);
194:    size_t __argp_fmtstream_write(argp_fmtstream_t, const char *, size_t);

File ../argp/argp.h:
526:    void __argp_usage(const struct argp_state *);
544:    int __option_is_end(const struct argp_option *);
532:    int __option_is_short(const struct argp_option *);
File ../bits/stdlib-bsearch.h:
20: void *__GI_bsearch(const void *, const void *, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t);

File ../csu/libc-start.c:
129:    
int __libc_start_main(int (*)(int, char **, char **), int, char **, int (*)(int, char 
**, char **), void (*)(void), void (*)(void), void *);

File ../elf/dl-runtime.c:
484:    void _dl_call_pltexit(struct link_map *, Elf64_Word, const void *, void *);
61: Elf64_Addr _dl_fixup(struct link_map *, Elf64_Word);
154:    
Elf64_Addr _dl_profile_fixup(struct link_map *, Elf64_Word, Elf64_Addr, void *, long 
*);
```

And many more...It is just the 1/100 part

Comment: `printf` is written in C and it has functions in it. So is `atoi`. And `main` is called by something, too.

Comment: I know this @user253751..But the question is why I am getting so many output results while others not?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of those functions come from glibc library, that is linked in runtime to every dynamic executable.

You can examine which libraries are linked by executing `ldd your-executable-name` and then examine reported .so files for the functions they have (by using gdb the same way).

Answer (score 0):

Try to link with `-Wl,--gc-sections  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` command-line options. It will remove all unused data and code and data from the executable. Then only used functions will be in your code.